# looking for a tool to convert PDFs to images and text (or html)

Tags: linux, macos, pdf

I need to convert about 500 PDFs to text and images or html?

A command line tool is ok, and I'm on a mac, so installable easily or with macports or brew is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you consider using the web service [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/). They support conversion of pdf to html.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), or its command-line program [`ebook-convert`](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html)

It's not always 100%, but it works for some PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

I went with installying poppler on mac and using the tools that come with it:

pdftohtml
pdftotext
pdfimage

works really well